# How would I reference a Linux man page in Harvard style?

Tags: citations

I'd like to reference a linux man page, in particular the man bash page. This is accessed through linux command line by typing 'man bash'.

Any ideas on how I would do that..?

Here is my try:

In text: Free Software Foundation, Inc. (2018)

In references: Free Software Foundation, Inc. (2018) man bash. Available at: General Command Manual

Comment: You can reference a _Linux man page_ the same way you would reference any software, since the manual is part of the software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my try, based on citation principles, [Open University's guide to citing software in Harvard format](http://www.open.ac.uk/libraryservices/documents/Harvard_citation_hlp.pdf), and [Mendeley's guide to core Harvard style](https://www.mendeley.com/guides/ultimate-citation-cheat-sheet).

In general, since the "man bash" page is a particular page, you may want to have the in-text citation specify that as the page/section. That will solve problems if you also want to reference the same manual about something else. Then you have just the more generic reference in the references section.

If this is the only manual citation:
In text: Free Software Foundation (2018)

In references: Free Software Foundation (2018) 'Bash manual page', *Linux* (Version X) [Computer program]. Available at [URL to get this version of Linux]. Copy of manual text available at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html (accessed DATE).

If referencing multiple parts of manual:

In text: Free Software Foundation (2018, bash manual page)

In references: Free Software Foundation (2018) *Linux* (Version X) [Computer program]. Available at [URL to get this version of Linux]. Copy of manual text available at https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/ (accessed DATE).

Does the Free Software Foundation itself host a version of the manual online? That would be the ideal reference for the text. I realize that this response is kind of clunky, but it helps readers find what they need without having to download (your version of) Linux.